# How to choose city from dropdown in simpleWeather.js?

Tags: jquery

So i have a problem where i have this script and dropdwon list but i dont know how to pass value from dropdown list to location ? So i have fixed location on start but when user check another from dropdown list it need to change weather temperature and city.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoNXGq here you can see what im trying to do...when user click on city i get dropdown list but how can i pass value from dropdow to location?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  loadWeather('Sarajevo'); //@params location,
});

function loadWeather(location) {
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: location,
    woeid: '',
    unit: 'c',

     success: function(weather) {
      html = '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i></h2>';
      html += '<div class="dropdown"><button style="background-color:transparent;border:none;" class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><span>' +weather.city+'</span><span style="color:white;margin-left:15px;margin-top:40px;" class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu" style="left:180px;"><li><a href="#">Zagreb </a></li><li><a href="#">Beograd </a></li></ul></div>';

      html += '<ul><li style="color:white;">'+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</li>';

      $("#weather").html(html);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
  });
    $('#js-geolocation').click(function() {
     var city = $("#city123").val();

    if(city!="")
       loadWeather(city)
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use 'data' attributes and set click handlers

JS

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.weather-link', function (e) {
  var city = $(this).data('city');
  loadWeather(city);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

HTML

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="left:180px;">
  <li><a class="weather-link" href="#" data-city="Zagreb">Zagreb</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="weather-link" href="#" data-city="Beograd">Beograd</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```